# How to prevent Richtextbox Table column width adjustment mess up text inside table?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, code-behind, flowdocument

I am making richtextbox (rtb) showing text, table, and image from .rtf file (rtf file load)

```
if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            string directoryPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(openFileDialog.FileName);

            TextRange range;
            FileStream fStream;
            range = new TextRange(RichTextControlLeft.Document.ContentStart, RichTextControlLeft.Document.ContentEnd);
            fStream = new FileStream(openFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            range.Load(fStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
            fStream.Close();
        }
```

I am currently facing problem in adjusting table to fit my rtb as the imported table is shown beyond my rtb

Here is the main problem, on the right, the table isnot fully shown
[image: The Main Problem]

Then I am trying to adjust table column width with this

```
                foreach (var item in table.Columns)
                {
                    item.Width = GridLength.Auto;
                }
```

The code resulting a strange behavior on the text
[image: Weird Text]

Is there any solution for this problem? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, there is a problem of the table in rtf format from the client
redraw the table, solve the problem